# Why object pointer prefix is added to the value? (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, enums, swift4

I am trying to parse the string of characters and save them to the array:

```
enum Token {
    case Number(Int)
    case Minus
    case Plus
}

var tokens = [Token]()

for char in ["1","-","3","+","9"] {switch char {
        case "0"..."9":
            //start of a number - need to grab the rest
            let digit = Int(String(char))!
            tokens.append(.Number(digit))
        case "+":
            tokens.append(.Plus)
        case "-":
            tokens.append(.Minus)
        default:
            //smth unexpected - need to send back an error
            print("ends...")
        }
}

print(tokens)
```

But the values are added with prefixes, that look like pointers. The result of the code above is:

```
[__lldb_expr_14.Token.Number(1), __lldb_expr_14.Token.Minus, __lldb_expr_14.Token.Number(3), __lldb_expr_14.Token.Plus, __lldb_expr_14.Token.Number(9)]
```

How can I get read of this prefixes so that the resulted array looked as:

```
[Token.Number(1), Token.Minus, Token.Number(3), Token.Plus, Token.Number(9)]
```

And why were these prefixes added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `Token` type does not implement `CustomStringConvertible`. You should implement it.

```
enum Token : CustomStringConvertible {
    case Number(Int)
    case Minus
    case Plus

    var description: String {
        // return a string that describes "self"
    }
}
```

One possible way to implement this is:

```
var description: String {
    switch self {
        case .Number(let x): return "Number(\(x))"
        case .Minus: return "Minus"
        case .Plus: return "Plus"
    }
}
```

Also note that enum cases should be in `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a novice in Swift. It helped me a lot.